# Trouble with RecurrenceTable using elements from a previously computed list

Tags: list-manipulation, recursion

When I use `RecurrenceTable` to solve a recursion relations, I encounter a problem, which is perhaps simple, but I do not understand why it is complaining. Here is a simple example. First, let's create a list

```
alist = Table[2^i, {i, 1, 100}]
```

and next evaluate

```
RecurrenceTable[{b[n] == alist[[n]] + b[n - 1], b[1] == 2}, b, {n, 1, 10}]
```

Then the results are

> Part::pkspec1: The expression n cannot be used as a part specification. >>
>   Part::pkspec1: The expression 1+n cannot be used as a part specification. >>
>   Part::pkspec1: The expression 1+#1 cannot be used as a part specification. >>
>   General::stop: Further output of Part::pkspec1 will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
>
> ```
> {2, 6, 14, 30, 62, 126, 254, 510, 1022, 2046}
> ```

Does anyone know where things go wrong and how to solve it?

In general I would like to know how to use the `ReccurenceTable` when the recursion relation depends on values from another precomputed list.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `RecurrenceTable` does some symbolic processing that leads to the unevaluated symbol `n` being given to `Part` as its 2nd argument. But `Part` only accepts integers as its 2nd argument. A work-around is:

```
Do[a[i] = 2^i, {i, 1, 10}]
RecurrenceTable[{b[n] == a[n] + b[n - 1], b[1] == 2}, b, {n, 1, 10}]
```

> `{2, 6, 14, 30, 62, 126, 254, 510, 1022, 2046}`

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I am using a earlier version of Mathematica. When I evaluate the code in your answer, it has the same problem!

Comment: @Wenzhe. What do you by "it has the same problem"?. There is no way my cod can produce an error message from `Part`. It make no use of `Part`.

Comment: Thank you. I shut down Mathematica and restart it, and the problem disappears. It works now.

Comment: Table[2^n - 2, {n, 2, 11}]