# How to specify an element of a list when using RecurrenceTable

Tags: list-manipulation, difference-equations

My problem is that I'm trying to get a list of refraction angles in a multilayer structure (for the sake of this example - with two types of refraction indices and eleven layers of them). The code is as follows:

```
theta0 = (1.535/2)*(Pi/180)
n = 11
nGaAs = 3.4;
nAlAs = 2.9;
nlayers = 
  {1, nGaAs, nGaAs, nAlAs, nGaAs, nAlAs, nGaAs, 
   nAlAs, nGaAs, nAlAs, nGaAs, nAlAs, nGaAs};
RecurrenceTable[
  {theta[i] == 
     ArcSin[(Extract[nlayers, i]/Extract[nlayers, i + 1])*Sin[theta[i - 1]]], 
   theta[0] == theta0}, 
  theta, {i, 1, n}]
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Extract::psl1: Position specification i in Extract[{1,3.4,3.4,2.9,3.4,2.9,3.4,2.9,3.4,2.9,3.4,2.9,3.4},i] is not applicable.

Is there any way to use a list of variables in `RecurrenceTable`? I'm fairly new to this, so maybe I missed something in the desctiption of `RecurrenceTable` or `Extract`, but still, does anyone know how to correctly formulate this in Mathematica?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It was already answered [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198139/trouble-with-recurrencetable-using-elements-from-a-previously-computed-list). `Do[nl[i]=nlayers[[i]],{i,Length[nlayers]}]`, then use this `nl` instead of `nlayers`.